# JavaScript Timeout reset mechanism

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, onload, cleartimeout

**What I want:**
There are two pictures that are being switched/swapped every three seconds.

I want to make it so that when the button is clicked, the picture switches and the auto-swap resets. So if the button is clicked, the image swaps and three seconds later, it will auto-swap, until the button is clicked again in which the cycle will repeat.

**What I have right now**
Currently, the problem is that: when the button is clicked, it messes up the timing of the auto-switches.

**Edit:**
Please don't create a new code base. Just modify mines. The code doesn't have to be an expert super concise level. I'm only three weeks into JavaScript (and it's my first programming language). I have to explain to classmates and it wouldn't be nice the code had elements I don't understand. So sorry for the inconvenience.

Right now I just need the button to correctly stop and restart the time.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        let reset = setTimeout(change, 3000);
        function change() {
            if(document.getElementById("picture").src == "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            setTimeout(change, 3000);
        }
        function fastChange() {
            clearTimeout(reset);
            if(document.getElementById("picture").src == "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="fastChange();">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" id="picture">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it is right conflating concise-ness with *expert level*. If there is something you don't understand about an answer, then the answer could be improved. So please comment on them.

Comment: I have also updated my answer to explain the code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT HOW YOU CLEARTIMEOUT:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var i;
        function change() {
            if(document.getElementById("picture").src == "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            i = setTimeout(change, 3000);
        }
        function fastChange() {
            clearTimeout(i);
            if(document.getElementById("picture").src == "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
            }
            i = setTimeout(change, 3000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(change, 3000)">
    <input type="button" onclick="fastChange();">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" id="picture">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use or link to w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your timer resets is because you are not clearing the timeout.

you need to make a reference to the timeout and then use clearTimeout() on it whne you make the fast change. I don't think it is possible or wise to do that inline the way you have it so you code needs to be refactored

```
let imgSrc1 = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'
let imgSrc2 = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'

let imgElement = document.getElementById('picture');
let timeout;

function change() {
   if(imgElement.src === imgSrc1) {
      imgElement.src = imgSrc2;
   } else {
      imgElement.src = imgSrc1;
   }
   if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
}

   timeout = setTimeout(change, 3000);
}
```

You don't even need the second function fastChange. Now you can sent the onClick listener to `change()` like this

document.getElementById('whatever you want to click').onCLick = change;

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `setTimeout` and updating the index as necessary. Just be sure to store the most recent timeout id so that it can be cancelled on reset using `clearTimeout`.

```js
// store the reference to the <img> that contains the picture
const pic = document.getElementById('picture')

// store a list (array) of the two picture urls
const sources = [
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350'
]

// used to store a reference to the interval timer you created.
var lastTimer
// a starting index of the list (i.e. which image we are up to right now)
var index = 1

// this functions swaps the image and sets a timer
function startRotation() {
  // update the index to the next one (goes 0-1-0-1->etc)
  index = 1 - index
  // sets the .src of the image element
  pic.src = sources[index]
  // starts a 3 second timer to call this same function again
  // but also stores a reference to the timer so that it can be cancelled
  lastTimer = setTimeout(startRotation, 3000)
}

// this functions resets the timer and restarts the process
function reset() {
  // stop the current timer if there is one
  if(lastTimer){
    clearTimeout(lastTimer)
  }
  // restart the process
  startRotation()
}

// start the swapping process on start
startRotation()
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="reset();">
<img id="picture">
```

Comment: I meant that I don't know why my code doesn't work. I don't know how knowing how your code works helps me understand why mines doesn't work. Can you tell me why my clearTimeout(reset) isn't stopping setTimeout? Maybe reset isn't defined or called correctly?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting and clearing timeouts in multiple places will work, but I prefer using a "main loop" and a variable to count frames.

Here's an example that uses `setInterval` and resets a `timer` variable when the button was clicked:

```js
const url1 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
const url2 = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";

function change() {
  picture.src = picture.src == url1 ? url2 : url1;
}

var timer = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  timer++;
  time.textContent = timer;
  if (timer === 30) fastChange();
}, 100);

function fastChange() {
  change();
  timer = 0;
}

picture.src = url1;
swap.onclick = fastChange;
```

```css
#picture {
  height: 70vh
}
```

```html
<button id="swap">SWAP</button> <span id="time"></span><br>
<img id="picture">
```

Comment: If you *prefer* a method, you should elaborate a bit on why. Seems a bit strange to run 30x the interval code. It also means the button click will be inaccurate up to 100ms from the next cycle. Not that this doesn't work well enough, just genuinely curious.

Comment: I updated the question. I realized I make the question incorrectly. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @MattWay I prefer it because to me it's less error-prone and more readable. The 30 x 100 was chosen arbitrarily, it could've been 60 x 50 instead. My answer isn't about presenting a solution that is to be copy-pasted to own code, it's about presenting an idea to be understood and implemented on your own.

Comment: @ChrisG I would politely argue that this method is not more readable, and more error prone. This is because it introduces an extra idea of a `timer`, and forces the reader to do the mental arithmatic to work out where the 3 seconds comes into play. The interval is not wrapped in a function which makes it difficult to refactor and update. For example, say I wanted to change it to 4 seconds, or 50ms. The first requires me to do unnecessary thought, and the second requires a full refactor of the method. Now say I wanted to cancel the interval all together. This requires another full refactor.

Comment: @MattWay We can throw around hypotheticals all day. Why don't we add a second slider that's supposed to change every 5 seconds? Basically all I need to do is add a single line `if (timer === 50) fastChange2();` However with your solution I have to refactor pretty much the entire script. I completely understand your point, which is why I qualified the usefulness of my answer in my previous comment.